# parameters tuning with GridsearchCV not giving best result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to tune parameters for my gradient boosting regressor.

First, only considering n_estimators, getting optimal n_estimators using `staged_predict` method I've got RMSE = 4.84 .

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

gbr_onehot = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators  = 1000,
    learning_rate = 0.1,
    random_state  = 214
)
model = gbr_onehot.fit(X_train, y_train)

errors = [mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
          for y_pred in gbr_onehot.staged_predict(X_test)]

best_num_trees =np.argmin(errors) 

GBR_best_num_trees_onehot = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators  =best_num_trees,
    learning_rate = 0.1,
    random_state  = 214
)

best_num_tree_model = GBR_best_num_trees_onehot.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = GBR_best_num_trees_onehot.predict(X_test)
print(best_num_trees)
print(f'RMSE with label encoding (best_num_trees) = {np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))}')


>>> 596
>>> RMSE with label encoding (best_num_trees) = 4.849497587420823
```

Alternatively, this time using GridsearchCV I've tuned n_estimator, learning_rate, and max_depth for each trees.

First, tunes n_estimator and learning_rate:

```
def rmse(actual, predict):
    predict = np.array(predict)
    actual = np.array(actual)

    distance = predict - actual

    square_distance = distance ** 2

    mean_square_distance = square_distance.mean()

    score = np.sqrt(mean_square_distance)

    return score

rmse_score = make_scorer(rmse, greater_is_better=False)

p_test = {
    'learning_rate': [0.15,0.1,0.05,0.01,0.005,0.001],
    'n_estimators' : [100,250,500,750,1000,1250,1500,1750]
}



tuning = GridSearchCV(estimator=GradientBoostingRegressor(max_depth=3,
                                                         min_samples_split=2,
                                                         min_samples_leaf=1,
                                                         subsample=1,
                                                         max_features='sqrt',
                                                         random_state=214),
                     param_grid = p_test,
                     scoring = rmse_score,
                     n_jobs = 4,
                     iid=False,
                     cv=5)

tuning.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and then using values from `tuning.best_params_`

```
p_test_2 = {'max_depth':[2,3,4,5,6,7]}
tuning = GridSearchCV(estimator = GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.05,
                                                           n_estimators=1000,
                                                           min_samples_split=2,
                                                           min_samples_leaf=1,
                                                           max_features='sqrt',
                                                           random_state=214),
                      param_grid = p_test_2,
                      scoring = rmse_score,
                      n_jobs=4,
                      iid=False,
                      cv=5)

tuning.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

used to get optimal max_depth parameter.

After I've plugged in parameters received from above and tested it

```
model = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    learning_rate=0.1,
    n_estimators=1000,
    min_samples_split=2,
    min_samples_leaf=1,
    max_features='sqrt',
    random_state=214,
    max_depth=3
)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print(f'RMSE = {np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))}')

>>> RMSE = 4.876534569535954
```

Which has higher RMSE than one I've got from only using `staged_predict`. Why is this the case? Also when I print( tuning.best_score_) why does it return a negative value?

Comment: You may get your question a little bit shorter and clear if you remove parameters with default values from your code.

Comment: Also you could use 'neg_root_mean_squared_error' instead of your function cause they are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh, it's so simple. You trying to compare RMSE metrics on test data, when you get your best fit parameters on your train data. It must be a different datasets with different quality values. If you calculate RMSE on your train data - you should get a better quality for the regressor with the best fit parameters.

**[UPD]**

For better understanding, take a look at the picture:
[image]

Here the Model Complexity corresponds to some of your tuning parameters (max_depth, etc), the Prediciton Error is similar to your RMSE measure and two curves according to your train and test datasets. So, when you searching for your best fit parameters with GridSearchCV - you are moving down the training curve and get the one RMSE value near High position, but it's is dangerous cause [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), however, RMSE on the test sample will not be optimal.

Comment: ?? Yes I am using it to measure RMSE for test data, my question is why tuning parameter with GridSearchCV is not giving optimal RMSE.

Comment: Let I explain that more clearly. In common, you may not get the best quality of the regressor for your test data with GridSearchCV, because GridSearchCV calculate RMSE on the train data and get the best quality for the train data - not for test.

Comment: Sometimes you may get a coincidence in the quality measured for test and train data with the optimal parameters taken from GridSearchCV. But it's may also not happens.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. GridSearchCV gets best quality for train data by using cross-validation therefore each cross validation step it makes prediction on new data and from there get parameters that gave best predictions. So to me it makes sense to get best accuracy by using parameters given from GridSearchCV