# GridSearchCV not giving the most optimal settings?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, xgboost

I'm working on a XGBoost model and I also tried the GridSearchCV from Scikit learn. After I did a search for most optimal parameter settings, I got this result:

```
Fitting 4 folds for each of 2304 candidates, totalling 9216 fits
Best parameters found:  {'colsample_bytree': 0.7, 'learning_rate': 0.1, 'max_depth': 5, 'min_child_weight': 11, 'n_estimators': 200, 'subsample': 0.9}
```

Now, after training a model with these settings and doing a prediction on unseen testdata (train/test set used), I got a result. As a test I was changing some settings and then I get a better result than with the most optimal parameters from the grid search.

Is this because the test set is different from the training data? If I have another testset, are those settings also different for the best score? I think both answers can be answered with yes, but how are other people working with this effect?

Because you get the results from the grid search, but do you always use these settings or are you doing the same as I do? **What will be your final setting for the model you want to deploy**?

Hope to receive some inspirational thoughts:)

My final code for train/test after manual fine tuning:

```
xgb_skl_tuned_2 = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    colsample_bytree = 0.7,
    subsample = 0.9, 
    learning_rate = 0.3,
    max_depth = 5, 
    min_child_weight = 13,
    gamma = 10, 
    n_estimators = 50
)

xgb_skl_tuned_2.fit(X_train_2,y_train_2)

preds_2 = xgb_skl_tuned_2.predict(X_test_2)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test_2, preds_2, squared=False)
print('Model RMSE: {}'.format(mse))
```

Also checked this thread: [parameters tuning with GridsearchCV not giving best result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607441/parameters-tuning-with-gridsearchcv-not-giving-best-result)

Comment: Try Optuna or random search

Comment: What's the benefit of that? Random search is maybe even worse, because the manually tuned parameters are within the grid I used. With random search you're not quite sure which random combinations are picked. Or is there a better explanation for your comment?

Comment: My bad, I was suggesting exploring options, grid-search often finds better params than random search, you can tinker with Optuna , [check this link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hamzaghanmi/xgboost-catboost-using-optuna#3.-XGBoost-using-Optuna-)

Comment: You say you changed the settings for the best fit model from the grid search, were those changes to other parameters that were part of the grid search or something completely new?

Comment: Good question, I only changed the parameters used in the grid search. Check out the two code blocks. The first one is the results from the gridsearch, the second one the model with manually fine tuned parameters. ie. Learning rate is 0.3 in the model, but best fit 0.1.